# updating user in custom wordpress table

Tags: sql

I have created a custom table in my wordpress project and I'm using wordpress sql queries to insert/update a user. When an email already exists, it should update the user with the same email, inserting a new user works, but updating one doesn't do anything. No errors either. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with my query? Here's my code:

```
global $wpdb;

        $fname = sanitize_text_field(esc_sql($_POST['fname']));
        $email = sanitize_email(esc_sql($_POST['email']));

        $uniqId = hexdec(uniqid());

        $prepare = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_registered_customers` WHERE email = %s", [$email]);
        $users = $wpdb->get_row($prepare);
        if(count($users) > 0){
            // wp_send_json_error(ErrorCodes::EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, 400);
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE `wp_registered_customers` SET fnmme=%s, email=%s, step1=1, step2=0, step3=0 WHERE email=%s", 
                [
                    $fname,
                    $email,
                    $email,
                ]
            );
            $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        } else {
            $wpdb->insert('wp_registered_customers', array(
                'customer_id' => $uniqId,
                'fname' => $fname,
                'email' => $email,
                'step1' => 1,
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main issues in your code:

1. Your `$wpdb->get_row($prepare)` will [return either an *object* or a `null`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/#return), so you can't do `if(count($users) > 0)` because `$users` is not an array.

   To fix that, just use `if ( $users )`.
2. There's a typo here: `SET fnmme=%s` — the field name should be `fname`.

So you should just need to correct those issues and your code would work as expected.

However, you should *not* use `$wpdb->get_results()` to run an UPDATE query, and instead,

- You can use [`$wpdb->query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/).
- Or in your case, you should use [`$wpdb->update()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) like so: (just replace the `$sql = $wpdb->prepare(...); $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);` in your code with the code below)

  ```php
  $wpdb->update(
      'wp_registered_customers',
      array(
          'fname' => $fname,
          'email' => $email,
          'step1' => 1,
          'step2' => 0,
          'step3' => 0,
      ),
      array( 'email' => $email )
  );
  ```

  But, are you sure you want to set `email` to the value of `$email`?

Additionally, I don't think it's necessary to call `esc_sql()` here:

```php
$fname = sanitize_text_field(esc_sql($_POST['fname']));
$email = sanitize_email(esc_sql($_POST['email']));
```

Comment: Thanks it works now, I used the ->update method. Will that automatically preven sql injection, or does that need additional code?

Comment: Yes, the `update` method will use the `prepare` method to prepare the query for a safe execution. The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/#parameters) also stated, "*Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped)*".

Comment: Ah okay, sometimes an email is used multiple times, how do I make sure only the first found row with a specific email gets updated?

Comment: I have already answered your question, so additional questions should be asked via separate posts. But what you asked is a generic PHP/programming question and should instead be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Nonetheless, you'd want to use `get_results()` then, i.e. `$users = $wpdb->get_results($prepare);`, and use `if($users && count( $users ) > 0)`. Then you'd want use the first item in the result, and then update by a unique field in your table, e.g. the `customer_id` field. So for example, pass `array( 'customer_id' => $users[0]->customer_id )` as the 3rd parameter for that function. (If you need further assistance, you should post a new question)

Comment: The better way, though, is - just like the user system in WordPress - ensure that every user registers using a unique email address, so if they used an email that already exists, show them an error and ask them to use another email, or to login to their account and update their email. And if the user is logged-in, add their unique field to your form, via a hidden field, then you can easily update the user without having to *guess* whether their data is the first/last/etc. in the result (i.e. the `$users` array).